# type mismatch error when comparing dates

Tags: excel, vba

This code produces a Type mismatch error on the second time through the For Next Loop.  I don't know why.

```
    Dim HD As Integer
    Dim HireDate2 As Date
    Dim HireDate3 As Integer
    Dim today As Date
    today = Now()
    HD = 2
    For HD = 2 To HireDate
        HireDate2 = Range("Z2:Z" & HD)
        MsgBox "Hire Date is " & HireDate2
       If (HireDate2 > today) Then
            HireDate3 = HireDate3 + 1
        End If
        HD = HD + 1
    Next HD
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: where is `HireDate` defined ? what kind of variable is it ? , also, from second time in the loop you are trying to `HireDate2` a range of cells, like `Range("Z2:Z3")` , which will result with a run-time error, if it's a date it need to read a single cell (unless you are looking for an array of dates) ?

Comment: Now im no vba expert but I think what's happening is that the head of the for loop basically does HD++ and then if HD is less than HireDate it continues, but this comparison is comparing an int with a date (sorry for my Java speak I hope you know what I mean)

Comment: `HireDate2` is going to be an array on every loop iteration after the first.

Comment: HireDate is defined as Long further up in the code. It's the last row in the column.   I thought HireDate2 would be the next row in column Z.

Comment: @aoswald so want `HireDate2` to get the value from next row ? like "Z3" , "Z4", etc... ? if you told us what is the goal of your code we might propose an optimal solution for you

Comment: Column Z is dates.  I need to make sure there are no dates in the future

Comment: @aoswald try the code in my answer below and see if it works as you intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below :

```
Dim HD As Long
Dim HireDate2 As Date
Dim HireDate3 As Long
Dim MyToday As Date
Dim HireDate As Long

MyToday = Date  ' <-- get today's date into a variable

For HD = 2 To HireDate
    HireDate2 = Range("Z" & HD).Value
    MsgBox "Hire Date is " & HireDate2
    If DateDiff("d", MyToday, HireDate2) > 0 Then ' <-- if HireDate 2 is in the future
        HireDate3 = HireDate3 + 1
    End If
Next HD
```

Comment: I think it is going to work.  I put the message box line in just to make sure I was comparing the right date so now I have to click through 18,000+ messages.  Looks like it's going to work so thank for the help.

Comment: @aoswald let me know what you need this code to do at the end, and the code can be modified to it

Comment: I take that back - it doesn't work.  It returned 0 after i put in several future dates to test it.

Comment: @aoswald  where did u put them ? Column Z ? Please share the rest of ur code? Also, do u have multiple sheets in your workbook ?

Comment: What is the syntaxt for the MyToday = Date line?   How do I get today's date defined as MyToday? it is comparing the correct dates, but I'm not sure it is comparing it to today's date

Comment: MyToday = Date is how you get today's date into the variable MyToday, run it in debug mode and see if it does

Comment: Yes it makes MyToday 3/21/2017